# Calendar / GregorianCalendar equivalent Javascript

Tags: java, node.js, time

```
  public static final long generateDateTime() {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(calendar, "GregorianCalendar.getInstance()");
    Date date = (Date)null;
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
    return (calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L - 0L) / 30L;
  }
```

How can I translate this function to node js / javascript?

Is this calendar.getTimeinMillis equivalent of Date.getTime() ?

Comment: As an aside, in Java don’t use `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). One of the (many) confusing things is that `GregorianCalendar.getInstance()` doesn’t necessarily give you a `GregorianCalendar`. So under all circumstances don’t write that.

Comment: I know it’s not what you asked, but for any Java programmer stumbling on this question, the correct and easy way to calculate half minutes since the epoch is `Instant.now().getEpochSecond() / 30`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Try with `moment(...).valueOf()`